# what are all the essential things to change in IIS 7 to make the web application speedup?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, asp.net, web-hosting

We are developed asp.net (.net 4 framework) web application and deployed in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008.But when we host the web application on our IIS 5.1 server on my local machine ie,windowsxp machine it seems to be work faster than one deployed in the Windows Sever 2008 machine.

most probably the most number of user access the web application at the same is approximately 50 only... Do i need to change any setting in application pool on IIS7.

When deploying i have never changed any settings in IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008.I have deployed using Visual Studio 2010 support.

I don't know about the reason why it is acting like this?

So, Could you please tell me what are all the essential things do i need to change in IIS 7 and also Windows Server 2008 to speedup my web application...

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box IIS 7 will run great. There shouldn't be any performance settings necessary to make it perform like the IIS5.1 box. There are some incremental tweaks that can be done like turning off modules that aren't needed, enabling compression, and things like that, but they likely aren't related to the performance difference that you're noticing.

There must be something else in play. Any chance that the database is making a remote call, or you have code that could be looking for a dependency that doesn't exist so that it needs to time out first?

A good way to narrow it down is to create a couple simple .htm and .aspx pages and see if you notice the same thing, then start adding to your site until you find out what causes the performance difference.  If you can track down what pages are slower that should offer some valuable clues.